# How to get an output of multiple characters set in a string? C#

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("Write your password and I will tell you how long it is");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();
        int howLong = password.Length;
        int check = password.IndexOf("!");
        int check1 = password.IndexOf("?");
        if (password.Contains("!"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long and I also found a symbol ! positioned in the {check}th place!");
        }
        else if (password.Contains("?")){
            Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long and I also found a symbol ? positioned in the {check1}th place!");
        }
        else if (password.Contains("? !"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long and I also found a symbol ? positioned in the {check1}th place and a symbol ! positioned in the {check}th place!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long");
        }
```

In the code above, everything works fine, if you find a char ''?'', it will print out the intended sentence, same goes with a char ''!'' and if theres no ''!'' or ''?'', then the ''else'' data type will execute. But how do I make execute ''else if'' data type if both of these symbols are found in the same string? As you can see in the code above, I added an option for that as well, but it never executes. If I put, for example, ''asdf!sds?sds'', the data type ''if'' will execute which only states the position of character ''!''. Why?

Comment: You will need to perform both checks, and before you do the separate checks

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: consider using a regex: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-regex-examples/

Answer (score 1):

First do a check for both then for single occurrences.

```
Console.WriteLine("Write your password and I will tell you how long it is");
    string password = Console.ReadLine();
    int howLong = password.Length;
    int check = password.IndexOf("!");
    int check1 = password.IndexOf("?");
    if (password.Contains("!") && password.Contains("?")){
        Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long and I also found a symbol ? positioned in the {check1}th place and a symbol ! positioned in the {check}th place!");
    } else if (password.Contains("!"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long and I also found a symbol ! positioned in the {check}th place!");
    }
    else if (password.Contains("?")){
        Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long and I also found a symbol ? positioned in the {check1}th place!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. But what If I wanted to check every known symbol there is? Would that exponentially increase my code just for the character check?

Comment: You'd write it differently, ie `for(int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++) Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long and I also found a symbol {password[x]} positioned in the {x}th place!");` - can't beat a bit of spelling out the user's password one char at a time!

Answer (score 1):

this is more compact

```
    Console.WriteLine("Write your password and I will tell you how long it is");
    string password = Console.ReadLine();
    int howLong = password.Length;
    int check1 = password.IndexOf("!");
    int check2 = password.IndexOf("?");

    if (check1 >= 0 && check2 >= 0) Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long and I also found a symbol ? positioned in the {check2}th place and a symbol ! positioned in the {check1}th place!");
    else
    {
        if (check1 > 0) Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long and I also found a symbol ! positioned in the {check1}th place!");
        else if (check2 > 0) Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long and I also found a symbol ? positioned in the {check2}th place!");
        else Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long");
    }
```

and this is more compact and generic

```
    var symbols = new string[] {"!","?","@"};
    string password = Console.ReadLine();
    int howLong = password.Length;
    Console.WriteLine($"Your password is {howLong} characters long");
    foreach (var symbol in symbols)
    {
      var index = password.IndexOf(symbol);
      if(index >=0)
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"and  found  a symbol {symbol} positioned in the {index.ToString()}th place");
      }
   }
```